# pass spinner data between activitys and use if statement with the given data

Tags: java, android, android-studio

so i Want to pass the selected item from the spinner to another activity and wanna use an if statement on the second activity. for example

if(spinnerPos selected item == "...") do that and that.

but i dont know what we get back from the Spinner (value or string).

Im programming with java on android studio.

My code is here: https://www.codepile.net/pile/K7AR9qeY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get string object ,and perform validation like this.

```
if (spinnerPos.equals("0")){
       // execute work
    } else{
     // do another
 }
```